# Regex for alpha numeric string with zero or one apostrophe inside

Tags: regex

I would like to build [A-Za-z] regex but with zero to one [\'] apostrophe inside that string.

Thanks.

Comment: What Regex flavor, and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like: `[A-Za-z]*'?[A-Za-z]*` seems like it would work--an arbitrary number of letters followed by an optional apostrophe, followed by an arbitrary number of more letters.

Answer (score 1):

```
^([a-zA-Z]+)?([[a-zA-Z]+\']{0,1})?[a-zA-Z]+$
```

Please find regex for alpha with apostrophe optionally.

Valid test case:

1. D'souza
2. Peter
3. Nil's

Invalid test case:

1. 'Tom
2. Mark'Two'

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[A-Za-z]*'?[A-Za-z]*$/
```

Depending on your regular expression flavor, that should work.